# How to make shipped Eclipse based application use all memory on users computer?

Tags: java, memory-management

I am shipping an Eclipse based application and want to have maximum Heap size. How can I make my application use all avilable memory on different machines. All I have found so far is the paramaters for setting heapsize that I can send the JVM but these are hardcoded. Basically I want the JVM to use whatever memory is available on the machine. Hard coding is not good enough.

Is there an easy way of doing this?

Comment: Do you ment a Eclipse-RCP-Application (Rich Client Platform)?

Comment: May I ask why you want to allocate the max possible heap size for a client application? In general one should have an idea of min/max heap required for given application?

Comment: Yes I mean Rich Client Platform. And yea in the best of worlds I would have a feeling for memory need. However with less than optimal implementations of heavy algorithms and no idea what datasets my users want to run that is not so easy. Better would be for them to be able to use whatever memory they have physically bought...

Answer (score 1):

Not possible using standard JVM features. JVM parameters specify the amount of memory to reserve (-Xmx...), not possible to specify "take all memory available". You could try a reasonable value like 1.2GB, that is the upper limit in Windows XP 32bit, for example. The problem is that the OS could not reserve all memory required by JVM so you must be more conservative.

The other approach is to calculate the available memory externally (script, native utility) and then set the JVM parameter with that value. NOt know if any installer like Install4J could achieve this.

Comment: I think is a controversial question about JVM. By design, seems to be you must specify how much memory you need, not allowing consuming all the machine memory, in order to make java "safer" and avoiding JVM exhausting the machine resources. You could have several init script files (eclipse.ini) and using some installer or native facility install one init script or another.